# CAT5E Troubleshooting

Tags: installation, rj-45, cat5e

I ran CAT5E through the walls in my house today. Everything looks fine but when I crimp the ends and attach them to my Rogers modem the cables are not working. I thought I was crimping it wrong but that does not seem to be the case - the Keystone pushdowns are wired in B and so are the cables ends.

Also, I tested it on a 100 foot free length cable crimping both ends and still the same. The modem is fine - tested that with a free patch cable.

I need help - no idea why the crimping is being an issue.

Comment: Have you ever made a good RJ-45 crimp previously?  First test should be for continuity.  Have you tested for continuity of each of the eight wires in that *"100 foot free length cable"*?

Comment: For a few dollars you should be able to get a cable tester which can confirm end-to-end connectivity. You get more fancy ones, but I'm thinking along the lines of https://www.ebay.com/itm/Practical-Network-Cable-Tester-for-Testing-RJ45-Ethernet-Cables-RJ11-Cables/283535672408?epid=9027626043&hash=item42040b0458:g:zgUAAOSwsftcMIyM

Answer (score 2):

Are you using solid core or stranded core CAT5E?

While you can the crimp solid core CAT5E with the right tools, with the tools intended for stranded core often the crimping won't make a good connection.

Solid core is intended for permanent cabling, you should be careful not to bend it too much, and it's easier to terminate it in wall plugs.

Use stranded core for the patch cables to connect your wall plugs to your devices.